# Echelon form of system with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

Suppose we have the (augmented) matrix A defined as

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      0&h&0&1\\
      1&1&h&-1\\
      2&h&1&-5
    \end{array}
\right]. $$

I have to discuss how many solutions it has depending on $h$. I have to first reduce it to echelon form. What I obtained is the following:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&h&1&-5\\
      1&1&h&-1\\
      0&h&0&1\\
    \end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&h&1&-5\\
      0&1-h/2&h-1/2&3/2\\
      0&h&0&1\\
    \end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&h&1&-5\\
      0&1-h/2&h-1/2&3/2\\
      0&0&-\frac{h-1/2}{2-h}&1-\frac{3}{2-h}\\
    \end{array}
\right]. $$

By looking at the last row, in order to have one solution, it must be defined the expression
$$
-\frac{1-\frac{3}{2h}}{\frac{h-1/2}{2-h}}.
$$
The solution corresponds to having the determinant not equal to zero: $h\neq0$ and $h\neq1/2$.

But for having infinitely many solutions or no solutions, I am lost. For infinitely many, the last row should contain only zeros, but what I got is
$$
-\frac{3}{2(2-h)}.
$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not come up with this RREF. But thanks @Moo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $h=0$, let's write the matrix:
  $$\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc|r@{}}
  0&0&0&1\\1&1&0&-1\\2&0&1&-5
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  The first row shows the system is inconsistent, so the set of solutions is empty.
- Similarly, if $h=1/2$, the matrix becomes
  \begin{align}
  &\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc|r@{}}
  0&\frac12&0&1\\1&1&\frac12&-1\\2&\frac12&1&-5
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc|r@{}}
  1&1&\frac12&-1\\0&1&0&2\\2&\frac12&1&-5
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc|r@{}}
  1&1&\frac12&-1\\0&1&0&2\\0&-\frac32&0&-3
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
  \rightsquigarrow &
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}crc|r@{}}
  1&1&\frac12&-1\\0&1&0&2\\0&0&0&0
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{@{}crc|r@{}}
  1&0&\frac12&-3\\0&1&0&2\\0&0&0&0
  \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix},
  \end{align} 
  so the solutions are an affine line, with equations
  $$x=-3-\frac z2, \qquad y=2.$$